# Passing an array to swiftmailer setTo()

Tags: php, arrays, swiftmailer

I am stuck heavily with this problem
I got around 100 emails to send mails to.
I want am trying to create one message and add all emails into the setTo method 
I have tried all but nothing works, below is my last attempt.
`$list` comes from a query.

```
foreach($list as $item) {
    $name[] = $item->name; $email[] = "'".$item->email."'";
    $id = 0;
    $id = $id +1;
}
$message->setTo(array(implode(',',$email)));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, better answer can be provided if you show the structure of  `$list` assuming the structure of `$list` is as you are using.

```
foreach($list as $item)    {

     $persons[$item->email] = $item->name;
     $id = 0;
     $id = $id +1;

  }
  $message->setTo($persons);
```

See here for info how to add recipients in setTo method

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/recipients